# Is there a way to tell Facebook to show nothing when link shared?

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags, meta

There are meta tag to tell Facebook what image to show and what text to display when a link is shared. I have a page that want to keep the element of surprise until opening the link. I have tried leaving the meta tag content blank, i.e.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="" />
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
```

However, Facebook just automatically get content from my site. Is there a way to tell Facebook I want to show nothing when my link is shared?

Comment: If you don’t supply title, description and thumbnail, Facebook will analyze the content and choose what it thinks are appropriate values on its own. You could try and deny access to the URL to the FB scraper - but I am not sure if that might affect sharing, news feed distribution etc. Perhaps you’re better off specifying values that help _“keep the element of surprise”_ - a white/blank thumbnail image, and a title/description that either incentivizes the user to click, or just gibberish that doesn’t give any information about the content.

Comment: Be aware though, that users might not like this kind of posts. I guess you know the kind of attention-wh*ring link posts, with descriptions like “This dude did X. You will not believe what happened next …”, that try to generate click-throughs to external sites. Many users report this kind of post when it show up in their news feed, as uninteresting/misleading, or even block the pages that posted them.

Comment: how about a blank character?